# barplot bars in specified interval width

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar plot with bars of specified width. I have tried a lot but so far nothing has worked for me.

Each element of `x` is the center of an interval. I would like the center of each bar to be in that position, and the width of this bar should correspond to the length of the interval. `y` contains the height of each bar. My goal is to obtain a bar plot with bars of varying width.

```
% inter contains the limits of my intervals
inter = [-32.6;-31.3;-20.3;-19.0;-15.4;-14.1;-11.7;-10.4;-8.8];

x = [ -31.6000; -19.8000; -17.4000; -13.1500; -10.5000; -8.8000];
y = [  2.3529; 1.0417; 1.3158; 1.5337; 2.5000; 1.0152];

% trying to create the bar plot, however, all widths are the same:
bar(x,y);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `patch` in order to draw each bar yourself. We can use `inter(k)` for the left and `inter(k + 1)` for the right edge of each bar `k`, and the height we already know is `y(k)`.

```
figure;
for k = 1 : length(y)
    xl = inter(k);
    xr = inter(k + 1);
    patch([xr, xr, xl, xl], [0, y(k), y(k) 0], 'b');
end
```

It turns out, you don't even need vector `x`.

Comment: +1 You could also replace the `patch` line by `bar((xl+xr)/2,y(k),xr-xl)`, adding `hold on` after `figure`